# compiling boost.spirit.karma example, customize_embedded_container.cpp fails

Tags: c++, boost

Using gcc or clang latest, boost 1.68 (or 1.69),

Compiling boost.spirit.karma example customize_embedded_container.cpp fails, unless replacing type with value_type in line 26.

The other useful example, customize_use_as_container.cpp also fails,  asking for value_type etc. in indirect_iterator, 
" no named type 'value_type' in 'std::iterator_traits' "

For the reference, the example : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/spirit/example/karma/customize_use_as_container.cpp

- Any that have a clue or  a working example for container-specialisation that is compiling in boost.spirit.karma ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54988199/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given my case, a skeleton for the solution, or rather a workaround just playing with the parts that really works easy in boost.spirit:

```cpp
namespace X {
  struct p { double t,v;};// point, time, value
  struct ts { // simplified time-series representation, time-axis computed
     bool s;
     double t0,dt;size_t n;// ti = t0 + dt*i
     std::vector<double> v;// v.size()===n
     p point(size_t i ) const  { return p{t0+dt*i,v[i]};}
  };

  //--would like to output grammar like {pfx:(true|false),data:[[t,v]..]}

  //--; first construct a container class out of ts, using boost iterator_facade 
  //--; to get away with few lines.(simplified..)
  struct ts_c {
     using value_type=p;// iterate over (t,v), t is computed, v is plain vector
     ts * c;
     struct iterator:public::boost::iterator_facade<iterator,p,boost::random_access_traversal..> { //..
       iterator(ts*c,size_t pos=0u):c{c},pos{pos} {}
        //.. plain vanilla impl. goes here according to boost::iterator_facade.
       private:
         ts* c;
         size_t pos;
     };
     using const_iterator=iterator;
     iterator begin() const;//.. etc. impl. of need it stuff.
  };
}
// use FUSION to adapt the ts-type, let last tuple member return the
// tuple members:
// 0 true if n>0, otherwise false
// 1 true if ts.s is true
// 2 returns a vanilla iterable container, ts_c exposing type p
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT(
    X::ts,
    (bool,bool, obj.n>0,/**/)
    (bool,bool,obj.s,/**/)
    (X::ts_c,X::ts_c, X::ts_c(&obj),/**/)
)
//-- then combining the boost spirit complex example to emit the point class p
namespace X {
    namespace ka=boost::spirit::karma;

    /** generate a point like [123.0, 3.14], or [123.0,null] if !isfinite. 
    *  using the complex example pattern given in boost::spirit,
    */
    template<class OutputIterator>
    struct point_generator:ka::grammar<OutputIterator,p()> {

        point_generator():point_generator::base_type(pg) {
            using ka::true_;
            using ka::bool_;
            using ka::omit;
            pg = 
                &true_ <<( '[' <<  double_<< ',' << double_ << ']')
                    |
                      omit[bool_]<<   ( '[' <<  double_<< ',' << "null" << ']')

            ;
        }
        ka::rule<OutputIterator,p()> pg;
    };

    /** @brief a ts generator
    *
    * outputs:
    *   {pfx:(true|false),data:[[t,v],..]}
    * or if empty
    *   {pfx:null,data:null}
    */
    template<class OutputIterator>
    struct ts_generator:ka::grammar<OutputIterator,ts()> {

        ts_generator():ts_generator::base_type(tsg) {
            using ka::true_;
            using ka::bool_;
            using ka::omit;
            tsg =
                &true_ <<"{pfx:"<<bool_<<",data:"<<( '[' << pt_ % ',' << ']')<<'}'
                    |
                      omit[bool_]<<  "{pfx:null: data:null}"

            ;
        }
        ka::rule<OutputIterator,ts()> tsg;
        point_generator<OutputIterator> pt_;
    };

}
```